# AFNetworking 2.0/Boost::Asio - Get JSON Data (network connection was lost)

Tags: json, http, network-programming, afnetworking, boost-asio

I've successfully sent JSON data to **BOOST Asio** utilizing **AFHTTPRequestOperationManager** but have been unsuccessful retrieving JSON data. I do ensure that I can reach the host via the **Reachability** capability within **AFNetworking**. I've tried several AFHTTPRequestOperationManager-based functions such as:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates=YES;
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager POST:@"http://xx.xx.xx.x:8888"
  parameters:nil
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     }];
```

But, I keep getting the same error:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was
>   lost." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x12fd7c580 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "The network connection was
>   lost." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http:/xx.xx.xx.x:8888/,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, NSErrorPeerAddressKey={length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes =
>   0x100222b82d3741040000000000000000}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=54,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://xx.xx.xx.x:8888/,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.}},
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://xx.xx.xx.x:8888/,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://xx.xx.xx.x:8888/,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=54, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.}

The Linux server example utilizes the **Boost Asio async_write** functionality with a write handler to ensure that the JSON POST is completed.

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>

using boost::property_tree::ptree;
using boost::property_tree::basic_ptree;

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using namespace std;

typedef std::string Blob;
const std::string NOOBJECT = "a";

class Server : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Server> {
private:
    const std::string AUTHSVCS = "xx.xx.xx.x:8888";

public:
    Server();
    virtual ~Server();
    void send(tcp::socket&, boost::asio::io_service&, std::string&);
    void on_send(const boost::system::error_code &, size_t);
    void genheader(Blob& body, std::string& request);
    void genbody(const std::string& reqtype, Blob& token, Blob& body);
};

Server::Server() {
}

Server::~Server() {
}

void
Server::genheader(Blob& body, std::string& request)
{
    cout << "Server::genheader" << endl;

    request += "POST / HTTP/1.1 \r\n";
    request += "Host:";
    request += AUTHSVCS;
    request += "\r\n";
    request += "User-Agent: ProteAuth/1.0 \r\n";
    request += "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
    request   += "Content-Type: application/json \r\n";
    request += "Accept: */*\r\n";
    request += "Content-Length: ";
    request += std::to_string(body.length());
    request += "\r\n";
    request += "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
    request += body;
}

void
Server::genbody(const std::string& reqtype, Blob& token, Blob& body)
{
    ptree requestTree;
    ptree requestElement;

    std::cout << "Server::genbody" << std::endl;

    // Add request token
    requestElement.put_value(token);
    requestTree.add_child(reqtype, requestElement);

    // Create (JSON) request
    std::stringstream ss;
    write_json(ss, requestTree, false);
    body = ss.str();
}

void
Server::send(tcp::socket& sock, boost::asio::io_service& io_service, std::string& request) {
    std::cout << "Server::send" << std::endl;

    try {
        async_write(sock, boost::asio::buffer(request), boost::bind(
                &Server::on_send,
                shared_from_this(),
                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

        io_service.run();
    } catch (exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return;
}
void
Server::on_send(const boost::system::error_code & error, size_t bytes_transferred) {
    std::cout << "Server::on_send" << std::endl;

    if (error) {
        std::cout << "Error: " << error.message() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Bytes sent: " << bytes_transferred << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Bytes sent: " << bytes_transferred << std::endl;
    }

    return;
}

int main() {
    try {
        boost::asio::io_service ioserv;
        tcp::acceptor acceptor(ioserv, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 8888));
        boost::shared_ptr<Server> sesh(new Server());

        //Blob 
        Blob token("a");

        // Generate URL body
        Blob body;
        sesh->genbody(NOOBJECT, token, body);

        // Generate Headers (append body)
        std::string request;
        sesh->genheader(body, request);

        for (;;) {
            tcp::socket newsocket(ioserv);
            acceptor.accept(newsocket);

            cout << "New Request" << endl;

            sesh->send(newsocket, ioserv, request);
        }
    } catch (exception& e) {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've used a REST Client [PAWS](https://luckymarmot.com/paw) to validate that the following content is retrieved:

```
    POST / HTTP/1.1 
    Host:xx.xx.xx.x:8888
    User-Agent: ProteAuth/1.0 
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
    Content-Type: application/json 
    Accept: */*
    Content-Length: 10
    Connection: close

{"a":"a"}
```

Does anyone know why I constantly lose connectivity to the network (Boost ASIO-embedded http-server)?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to determine the issue with the JSON data transfer between the **async_write** function (***BOOST::Asio***) and the **AFHTTPRequestOperationManager** (***iOS***). It was simply a a badly formed header that was updated in the genheader function as follows:

```
void Server::genheader(Blob& body, std::string& request)
{
    cout << "Server::genheader" << endl;

    request += "HTTP/1.1 200 OK \r\n";
    request += "Content-Length: ";
    request += std::to_string(body.length());
    request += "\r\n";
    request += "Content-Type: application/json \r\n";
    request += "Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n";
    request += body;
}
```